# Emacs -- creating an interactive only quasi-post-command-hook

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm interested in creating an interactive-only quasi-post-command-hook that runs based upon user-defined-criteria, such as:

- Up (interactive);
- Down (interactive);
- Left (interactive);
- Right (interactive);
- Any (interactive) key that inserts text into the buffer -- e.g., aA-zZ; 0-9; space; !@#$%^&*()-+=.;, return/enter, delete/backspace,  etc.
- Mouse scroll-wheel (up / down) (interactive).

I believe that the post-command-hook includes more, and I'd like to limit / control when the hook is activated.

Any guidance on how to create such a hook would be appreciated.

---

**May 3, 2013**:  Draft example based upon the answer by @phils below.

```lisp
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'quasi-post-command-hook)

(defvar quasi-this-command-functions '(next-line previous-line left-char right-char
  self-insert-command newline delete-backward-char delete-forward-char
  indent-for-tab-command mwheel-scroll lawlist-mwheel-scroll end-of-visual-line
  beginning-of-visual-line end-of-buffer beginning-of-buffer lawlist-forward-entity
  lawlist-backward-entity left-word right-word forward-word backward-word)
"Variable list of functions that trigger the `quasi-post-command-hook`.")

(defvar quasi-major-mode-inclusions '(text-mode emacs-lisp-mode)
"Variable list of major modes where the `quasi-post-command-hook` operates.")

(defun quasi-post-command-hook ()
  (unless (minibufferp)
    (when
      (and
        (memq major-mode quasi-major-mode-inclusions)
        (memq this-command quasi-this-command-functions))
      (message "this-command:  %s" this-command))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to test the `this-command` variables.

e.g. `C-u M-x apropos-variable RET this RET`:

```
real-this-command
   This is like `this-command', except that commands should never
   modify it.
this-command
   The command now being executed.
this-command-keys-shift-translated
   Non-nil if the key sequence activating this command was
   shift-translated.
this-original-command
   The command bound to the current key sequence before remapping.
```

Answer (score 1):

Enumerating the commands you know should trigger this hook (using `this-command`) is of course an option, but "it doesn't scale".  Maybe you could do better if you tried to characterize what those commands have in common with each other and that the other commands don't have.

Comment: The two groups are essentially:  `point` has moved manually as a result of the user pressing an interactive key; or, the buffer was manually scrolled up or down.

Comment: So maybe you can remember the previous point in `lawlist-last-point` and then compare it to current point to see if the last command moved point.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion -- I'll keep working on this over the next few days, as time permits, and I'll report back.